# dynamic drop down while allowing multiple option select for the child drop down

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I need to load data dynamically into two child drop downs according to the selected value in a parent drop down. At the same time child drop down boxes should allow multiple option select. for example, if i select value 1 then data should be loaded to one child drop down. if i select value 2 then other child drop down should be loaded. if I select value 3 then both child drop downs should load data. I have succeeded that. but the problem is when I use selectpicker with multiple attribute in select tag, above mentioned mechanism is working, but do not show data in child drop downs. I can't figure out what is the problem in there.
My html code is below

```
            <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-4" for="sel4">Designation:</label>
                   <select name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control col-sm-5">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                   @foreach($type as $items)
                    <option value="{{$items->id}}">{{$items->type}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-4">Registrar Division:</label>

                  <label class="col-sm-4">Birth and Death Division:</label>
                  <select name="birth_death_div[]" multiple id="birth_death_div" class="form-control col-sm-4 selectpicker">
                    <option value="">Select a Birth and Death Division</option>

                  </select>
                   <label class="col-sm-4"></label>
                  <label class="col-sm-4 mt-2">Marriage Division:</label>
                  <select name="marriage_div[]" multiple id="marriage_div" class="form-control col-sm-4 mt-2 selectpicker">
                    <option value="">Select a Marriage Division</option>

                  </select>

                </div>
```

first drop down is the parent.

following is the javascript code

```
$('#designation').change(function(){
      var desig_type = $(this).val();
      var ds= $('#ds').val();
      var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

      $.ajax({
          url:"{{ route('addregistrar.fetchdiv') }}",
          method:"POST",
          data:{desig_type:desig_type, ds:ds, _token:_token},

          success:function(data){

             data = JSON.parse(data);

            if(data.division_type=="1"){
              $('#marriage_div').html(data.output);
              $('#birth_death_div').html('');
            }

           if(data.division_type=="2"){
              $('#birth_death_div').html(data.output);
              $('#marriage_div').html('');
           }

           if(data.division_type=="3"){
              $('#marriage_div').html(data.output_m);
              $('#birth_death_div').html(data.output_bd);
           } 

          }
       })

   });
```

controller code

```
         $data_m = DB::table('registrar_division') //get marriage divisions
               ->where('divisional_secretariat_id', $ds)
               ->where('div_type',$marriage_div)
               ->get();

                 $output_m = '<option value="">Select a Division</option>';
                 foreach($data_m as $row_m)
                 {

                  $output_m .= '<option value="'.$row_m->$id.'">'.$row_m->$name.'</option>';

                 }
```

`output`, `output_bd` are also same as `output_m`

Data is passing correctly to child drop downs. but not showing any data.
My controller code is much long and it is working fine. Problem occurred when added selectpicker class to select tag.
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: can you add `data` op as well in your question?Also this is bootstrap selectpicker ?

Comment: yes bootstrap selectpicker

Comment: then use `$("#yourselectid").selectpicker("refresh");` after appending data to select and see if that works

Comment: @Swati that worked. Thank You very much